# check / uncheck a single checkbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a single HTML page with 30+ check boxes (

How do I configure this script to remember only the check box I selected (Remember only that one checked or unchecked)

This is the script that I use:

```
$(function(){
    var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
    $('input').prop('checked', test || false);
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('input')` matches *all* inputs. Give it a more specific selector (preferably the `id` of the input you want to remember.

Answer (score 0):

This code saves the state of all checkboxes between sessions:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(idx) {
  this.checked= localStorage.getItem('input'+idx) === 'true';
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(idx) {
  $(this).click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('input'+idx, this.checked);
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/dju2vooq/)

---

If inputs are added, switched around, or deleted, you'll need a different method.

If each input has an `id`, you can use this code instead:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(idx) {
  this.checked= localStorage.getItem('input'+this.id) === 'true';
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  localStorage.setItem('input'+this.id, this.checked);
});
```

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fbLrtq0w/)